# Modify Unity WebGL Build URL

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-webgl

How to change the URL of the Unity WebGL build? The build settings do not have any setting to change the URL or the port number. However here are my findings.

[image]

[image]

The following path contains the build tools for WebGL

```
Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.4.9f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\WebGLSupport\BuildTools
```

And these are the build-tools for WebGL

```
Brotli/
data/
Demangle.js
DynamicJslibLoader.js
Emscripten/
emscripten.config
Emscripten_FastComp_Win/
Emscripten_Win/
ExceptionLogger.js
lib/
prejs/
SimpleWebServer.exe*
SimpleWebServer.pdb
uglify-js/
UnityLoader.js
UnityLoader.min.js
WebGLTemplates/
websockify/
```

Unity uses the `SimpleWebServer` executable to run the server locally. This program takes the following parameters

```
usage: SimpleWebServer.exe source_directory [port] [pid] [<wasmEncoding>]
```

Is there anywhere we can set the port and pick the directory when this happens in the WebGL build process?

Comment: Looks like it [calls a function called `GetRandomUnusedPort`](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/184963/121653) so setting it doesn't seem to be possible. :(

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to set the port for Unity's web server.

To test the web build locally you can use any webserver (apache, IIS, python, etc.) instead of relying on the build and run button in Unity.

You can install python3 if you don't have already and run this from the web build directory:

```
$> python -m http.server 8080
```

Now you can run your game in browser by going to http://localhost:8080